# Maclaurin Series of $\cosh \frac{1}{z^2}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Starting with standard Maclaurin series for $\cosh z$

\begin{align*}
  \cosh z &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n!)} \\
\end{align*}

Then substitute $\frac{1}{z^2}$ in for $z$:

\begin{align*}
  \cosh \frac{1}{z^2} &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n!)z^{4n}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2! z^4} + \frac{1}{4!z^8} + \cdots \\
\end{align*}

My textbook, Complex Variables and Applications by Brown, ISBN 978-0073383170, http://a.co/ezDKyrn, on page 231 says:

\begin{align*}
  \cosh \frac{1}{z^2} &= 1 + \frac{1}{2! z^2} + \frac{1}{4!z^4} + \frac{1}{6! z^6} + \cdots \\
\end{align*}

Is this just a mistake in the textbook or am I doing my Maclaurin series incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, yours is correct (although it's not a Maclaurin series unless it's around where the variable is zero; this is a Laurent series). The one you say the book has is the Laurent series for $\cosh{\left( \frac{1}{z} \right)}$ (note the lack of square).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why it's a Laurent series and not a Maclaurin series? The $\cosh z$ series is Maclaurin, right? I did the derivation with the Maclaurin approach. If the $\cosh z$ series is Maclaurin, what makes the $\cosh \frac{1}{z^2}$ series not?

Comment: A Maclaurin's series must contain only non-negative powers of $(z-z_0)$, $z_0=0$ in your case.

Comment: A Maclaurin series has the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n$. A Taylor series is the same idea, but at the point $a$, not necessarily $0$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (z-a)^n$. A Laurent series is more general than both of these: a Laurent series centred at $a$ looks like
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (z-a)^n$$
(so in general it can contain negative powers). Whereas Maclaurin and Taylor series converge on the interiors of discs (or everywhere, or not at all), a Laurent series in general converges on an annulus $r_1 < |z-a|<r_2$.

Comment: @mathlover is right, that the reason the $\cosh \frac{1}{z^2}$ series is not Maclaurin but a more general Laurent series is because it involves negative powers of $z$ or $(z-z_0)$. Thanks to you both!